# Why are actions on deleted questions not shown in my activity list?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, recent-activity

I made a comment on a question in Stack Overflow. Then some minutes later I wanted to navigate to the question again for making another comment. So, I went to my profile / Activity / all actions / comments. But my comment was not there.

I found the question via my browser history and saw that it is deleted. I can see the deleted question with my comment because I have more than 10k privilege on Stack Overflow. So, why is it hidden in my activity history?

Shouldn't this be changed?

---

This is not the same issue as in [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted), which specifically deals with questions and answers, but not other activities like comments or votes.

Comment: Ah my bad, I read that too fast then. in any case wouldn't that just clutter the "actions" tab on one's profile? I guess that on SO at least, a lot of people leave "please explain what you tried/don't give a screenshot, include your code" etc; if they were all left visible after deletion, wouldn't that be a mess?

Comment: It might be a workaround to "favorite" a post that you anticipate will be deleted but want to maintain a link to.  With 10K reputation you will be able to see the deleted post and its Comments, although no new Comments can be posted.

Answer (score 3):

If such questions would still be shown, then a low rep user could (ab)use it to post comments to any questions the user does still want to have access to after the question is deleted ... eg using a comment like

> mark this post to always have access to it, even if it is deleted and I still have insufficient rep to access it anyway.

Comment: They would only be able to see their own comments. If they clicked on the links to the post they would just be taken to the normal "this post has been deleted" page.

Comment: I would only want to see the entry in the activity history when I can also see the deleted question. Users can see their own deleted questions, so they should see comments on their own deleted questions. 10K users can see all deleted questions, so they should see all their comments on all deleted questions. Users should not see comments on deleted questions when they would not be allowed to see the question